# MongoDB, accidentally changed permissions of all files

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

So I already resolved my issue by just rebuilding a new server but I don't understand why this happened. I am running mongo 4.2.* on Ubuntu 18. So overnight some mongodb folders /var/lib/mongodb and /var/run/mongodb ownership got changed to root from mongodb and mongod service crashed. No idea why. So I went to recursively change ownership back to mongodb with the following sequence of commands (copied directly from history).

```
  387  sudo chown -R mongodb.mongodb /var/run/mongodb/
  388  sudo service mongod start
  389  sudo service mongod status
  390  tail mongod.log --lines 25
  391  ls -al /var/lib/
  392  sudo chown -R mongodb.mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/
  393  sudo service mongod start
  394  sudo service mongod restart
```

When I restarted I came to an error. After some research I saw that 90% of files, including those in /, changed ownership to mongodb.

I could no longer use sudo, no longer change users, etc. Since everything was changed to be owned by mongodb. How did this happen?? I dont understand how the commands I typed ended up changing all permissions..

Comment: Does anyone else have access to the machine? If not, perhaps you did and just don't remember.

Comment: They do, and I saw in splunk logs that he happened to be logged in at the same time and we were working on mongodb i THINK. But honestly, I was doing commands pretty fast. Unless by it was by major coincidence he typed "sudo chown -R mongodb.mongodb /" around the same time I did. Unfortunately the splunk logs doesnt capture command line history from him. Is it possible that some files in mongodb/ were linked to other files causing this chain of permission changes?

Comment: If he changed the ownership from mongodb to root, then that would explain how they got that way. It's also possible that he did indeed change the ownership of `/` to mongodb. If that's what he did, then perhaps he shouldn't have sudo access on the server.

Comment: You might want to check the `last` command to see when other users recently logged in. Perhaps one of your colleagues restarted MongoDB using `sudo mongod ...` instead of using the `service` (which would run the process as `root` instead of the `mongodb` user in the service definition). Running as `root` can prevent the MongoDB service from later starting successfully as a non-root user, since newly created files would be owned by `root`. There should be more information in the MongoDB logs regarding any file permission errors that led to the process shutting down.